# phpspreadsheet: function 'sum' problem output with '@'

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

when I try to use the 'sum' function with phpspreadsheet, the output returns with '@'. The logical sequence works correctly (therefore the cells with which to add the sum are correct). SEE IMAGEcorrect). SEE IMAGEVEDERE IMMAGINE.

INPUT:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E' . $row, '=SOMMA(E4:E' . $row_1 . ')');
```

OUTPUT:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCe3o.png)

Comment: `@` is the implicit Intersection operator, introduced in Excel 365.  It will be included in a formula when you write to `.Formula` or `.Value`.  To avoid it you must write to `.Formula2`.  Does your library support that?

Comment: i don't know, i use this package 'phpspreadsheet'

Comment: And i don't know how to write to .Formula2

Answer (score 1):

Phpspreadsheet recognizes functions only in English.

That would be like this:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E' . $row, '=SUM(E4:E' . $row_1 . ')');
```

Comment: Hi, this was very helpful for me. I was getting a  " ¿ NOMBRE ? " error in the cell of my Excel, it was because I was writting "SUMA" instead of "SUM".
Thank you!